# How to use `%value%` in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript and I see `%value%` in a code but I do not know what does it mean or how to use it. Can anyone please help me explain to me. Thank you very much.

```
var formattedLocation = HTMLworkLocation.replace("%data%", work.jobs[job].location);
```

Comment: In what context?

Comment: Could you post the code?

Comment: For example, `var formattedLocation = HTMLworkLocation.replace("%data%", work.jobs[job].location);`

Comment: the first instance of the string `%data%` will be replaced with the value of `work.jobs[job].location`

Comment: There's nothing special about `%data%`, it's just a string that you're searching for in the `HTMLWorkLocation` variable.

Comment: That looks like MSSQL / C# code.  That is not a valid regex for Javascript, if that is what you are trying to do.  That will explicity look for the string:  "%data%" and it looks more so like you are looking for the FIRST occurance of data with anything before and anything after it.

Comment: So `data` is a string and it will show in the DOM?

Comment: @Fallenreaper Why would it need to be a valid regexp?

Comment: @Fallenreaper replace doesn't only take regex it also takes a string `str.replace(regexp|substr, newSubstr|function)`

Comment: I know replace takes either a regex OR a string, but the string looks like he is looking for the first instance of data with anything before or after it.  So his code will look for an explicit string, but the string itself looks suspeciously like regex.

Comment: Either the OP is looking for explicit string, OR he is trying to do a regex.  I feel the question itself needs a little bit more in terms of information

Answer (score 5):

`"%data%"` is just a literal string. This code will take the value of `HTMLWorkLocation`, look for the first occurrence of `%data%` in it, and replace that with the value of `work.jobs[job].location`, and store the resulting string in `formattedLocation`.

```js
var work = {
  jobs: [{
    location: "Home office"
  }]
};

var job = 0;

var HTMLworkLocation = "John is located at %data%";

var formattedLocation = HTMLworkLocation.replace("%data%", work.jobs[job].location);

console.log(formattedLocation);
```

This is probably part of a template system that's used to replace placeholders like `%data%` with values that come from a table.

Comment: Almost understand but can you please explain more with an example?

Comment: I provided an example.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `string.replace` which takes a string or regular expression as it's first argument. Based on the code you posted it looks like you're looking for the string `"%data%"` (or whatever string you're looking for) in `HTMLworkLocation` and replacing it with the value in `work.jobs[job].location`. Then it is being stored in `formattedLocation`.

I would put a `debugger;` line after that line of code so you can see what the values are in the debugger console. That might help make more sense of things.

[Here is more info on the `str.replace` method with some examples](http://You're%20using%20%60string.replace%60%20which%20takes%20a%20string%20or%20regular%20expression%20as%20it's%20first%20argument.%20Based%20on%20the%20code%20you%20posted%20it%20looks%20like%20you're%20looking%20for%20the%20string%20%60%22%DAta%25%22%60%20(or%20whatever%20string%20you're%20looking%20for)%20in%20%60HTMLworkLocation%60%20and%20replacing%20it%20with%20the%20value%20in%20%60work.jobs[job].location%60.%20Then%20it%20is%20being%20stored%20in%20%60formattedLocation%60.%20%20%20I%20would%20put%20a%20%60debugger;%60%20line%20after%20that%20line%20of%20code%20so%20you%20can%20see%20what%20the%20values%20are%20in%20the%20debugger%20console.%20That%20might%20help%20make%20more%20sense%20of%20things.%20%20%20[Here%20is%20more%20info%20on%20the%20%60str.replace%60%20method%20with%20some%20more%20examples.][1]%20%20%20%20%20%20%20[1]:%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)